# How to mask DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Let's say I have a DLL that provides math calculus functions. To use it, I include the `using Colhq.Math.Basic;` namespace.

How could I use it by adding a statement like `using Blala.Functions.Math;`?

How could I use everything (methods, enums, etc.) from a DLL by using a different namespace?
Is there a one-shot way to wrap or mask a DLL?

Comment: I'm usually quite adamant about getting on with answering questions on SO rather than questioning the motive, but I really do have to ask, why do you want to mask the namespace? Does it have some rude words? Is it copyrighted (DLL Library)?

Comment: I have to provide a DLL with some functionality as a homework. I have found a solution that provides this functionality and much more and I want to use it without having the others know everything is delegated. As the deadline is very tight, this way I will save time.

Comment: Respectfully, I would suggest that you do your own homework. If the assignment allows you to use external libraries, then you can probably use the external DLL without masking it. If the assignment does not allow you to use external libraries, you need to bite the bullet and write them yourself.

Comment: Can I have your teacher's email address, by chance? Unmasked, by the way.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: actually I ended up implementing those algorithms myself; it took me 2 hours and I have learned nothing new :(

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Ha ha ha! good one! however, I came here because I needed a solution fast, not because I did not want to do it by myself - what I have finally did. However, I have learned nothing new - I only had to implement a couple of algorithms. It would be comfortable for me to know that my request had no solution.

Comment: @ytrewq: Welcome to the world of school, where sometimes you have to do things you don't want to do, and you have to learn some things that seem pointless.  Do your school work with integrity; you will become a better human being.

Comment: @Robert Harvey if every reinvented wheel would grind your toes would you continue reinventing wheels :) ?

Comment: @ytrewq: All the time.  If you think it's bad now, wait until you get out into the workforce.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [namespace alias](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/34419).

Comment: Can this be used even if I do NOT have access to DLLs source code ?

Comment: Yes, but the condition you gave Andrew seems to preclude the use of an alias.  What are you trying to do, anyway?  Hide someone else's DLL in your code?  That doesn't seem prudent.

Comment: Yes, I want to use everything that is under a namespace with a different namespace. I want to provide the functionality within a DLL under a new namespace (the old namespace will not have to appear in the code that uses my wrapper DLL). Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the following at the top of each file where you need the alias:

`using Blala.Functions.Math = Colhq.Math.Basic`

Comment: I do NOT want `Colhq.Math.Basic` to appear in my source code;

Comment: This won't work. Aliases can only be represented by one identifier, not a succession of dotted ones like usual namespaces.